# How to find sum of columns in datatable in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using following code but not getting any results rather blank and throwing errors like

```
Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
```

THird and fourth column are `FF` and `BW`

data table value will be like

```
C1   c2    FF  BW

56  122    3   4

23  45         7

45  78     6   

12  34     6   9
```

i want to get      Total FF as  15 and toatal BW as  20

```
   decimal FF = 0,  BW = 0, AF = 0;

 DataTable table = dtPointLinks.Clone();
                table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
                table.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(string);
                table.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(string);
                table.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(string);


                // Declare an object variable.
                object objFF;
                objFF = table.Compute("Sum(FF)", string.Empty);
                object objBW;
                objBW = table.Compute("Sum(BW)", string.Empty);
                FF = Convert.ToDecimal(objFF);
                BW = Convert.ToDecimal(objBW);
```

any idea what went wrong here

Comment: Looks like you are having null values in some columns, Is your table having records?What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: you have to deal with nulls.  this has not been considered at all i your code.  do search on `Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types` and research how others have solved this problem

Comment: Why do you compute Sum in string column?

Comment: Why it's not `int?`

Comment: If i change to int also no impact

Comment: Try to set the filter to `FF IS NOT NULL` instead of an empty string (and the other one to `BW IS NOT NULL` (not sure that will work, though).

Comment: Is linq allowed? `var sum = dt.AsEnumerable().Sum(x => x.Field<int>(2));`

Answer (score 0):

in your case you can try the traditionally **for loop** to get your desired answer.

Here is the sample code below shows how you can achieve that.

```
        decimal FF = 0;
        decimal BW = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if(dt.Rows[i]["FF"].ToString() != "")
            {
                FF += Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["FF"].ToString());
            }
            if (dt.Rows[i]["BW"].ToString() != "")
            {
                BW += Convert.ToDecimal(dt.Rows[i]["BW"].ToString());
            }     
        }
```

Final result will be **FF = 15** and **BW = 20**.

Hope this can help you.